# Can standard healing spells target plants?

Tags: dnd-5e

If a player chopped a tree with an axe, leaving a big wedge cut into it, could it be healed with say, a cleric's Cure Wounds?

It says a 'Creature', which I would suppose means any living thing, although I guess undead are also creatures since it has an explicit comment about the spell not working on them.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate because I believe the base-line questions *are* fundamentally the same ("Are plants creatures?"). If you disagree or require addition help, please let us know in the comments or [edit] your question to further specify what's unclear. Please also note that there's nothing wrong with asking duplicate questions (as long as your not just copy/pasting them word for word) as they help other people who may be searching for a particular question using different keywords.

Comment: Yes, I read that question before posting, but it wasn't really clear. It talked about magical plants, and plant creatures, it didn't give any definitive explanation other than  `Generally, any plant that doesn't come with a stat block should not be considered a creature.` - According to what rules? I ask because how would a druid for example heal a plant? Surely that's something they can do using magic.

Comment: If your question is *"how would a druid, for example, heal a plant?"* then you might be better off asking that instead. If you wish to know what rules the basis for *"Generally, any plant that doesn't come with a stat block should not be considered a creature"* come from then you might be better off leaving a comment on that answer asking them to explain further.

Comment: This question has entered the Reopen review queue - I think that, in its current form, it _is_ a duplicate. If you edit the question to ask "_how would a druid heal a plant_" or similar, as Purple Monkey suggests, then at that point I would say that this should be reopened. For now, I shall hit the Leave Closed button.

Comment: Very well, I will re-ask, but the question will be pretty much the same - How would a druid heal a plant given that their healing spell at level 1 targets a 'creature' - is a plant considered a creature?

Comment: I don't think your new question's the same (even though I understand that the underlying thing you're trying to get at is, of course, the same). This question focuses on the definition of a plant, which makes it a duplicate of "_Are plants creatures or objects?_", but your new question focuses on what you want to achieve, which is how to heal a plant given that it isn't a creature. You see - the new question understands that a plant doesn't count as a creature, so now you can get past that hurdle and just find out what you really want to know - how to heal it. Your new question is much better!

Comment: Just to be clear - when I said your new question is much better, I don't think this question is _bad_ (I upvoted it), but the focus of it wasn't quite right, and thus being marked as a duplicate didn't answer your underlying question. Your new question _is_ that underlying question, so hopefully you'll get much more satisfactory answers from it. That is the way in which I think your new question is better (i.e. better for you to get what you want out of it).